# Retrieve file size from multiple file uploads

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this code below

```
$("#btn_save_development").bind("click", function () {


    var devMainImgSize = parseFloat($("#dev_main_image")[0].files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg1Size = parseFloat($("#devListingImg1")[0].files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg2Size = parseFloat($("#devListingImg2")[0].files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg3Size = parseFloat($("#devListingImg3")[0].files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg4Size = parseFloat($("#devListingImg4")[0].files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg5Size = parseFloat($("#devListingImg5")[0].files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg6Size = parseFloat($("#devListingImg6")[0].files[0].size / 1024).toFixed(2);

    if(devMainImgSize > 800)
    {
        alert("The Main Listing Image too large. It should not be above 800KB. Please upload an image with a smaller size");
        return false;
    }

    if (devListingImg1Size > 800 || devListingImg2Size > 800 || devListingImg3Size > 800 || devListingImg4Size > 800 || devListingImg5Size > 800 || devListingImg6Size > 800) {
        alert("One or all of the Development Listing Image(s) is above 800KB. Please ensure none of the development listing images are larger than 800KB");
        return false;
    }
});
```

which i want to use to check the size of images being uploaded via the file uploads. The problem i am having is, if i try to check the size of file in just one file upload the code works and i see the Javascript alert but when i try to check for multiple files i get this error in my browser console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`. My question is, how can i check the file sizes of all the files in my file uploads? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that if you do not have all of the `input` uploads filled with an image, then this error gets thrown. If you fill all of them, the error won't occur. You can create a function that checks whether the inputs are filled. Then if they aren't filled return a value of `0`. Otherwise return the size for the rest of the calculations you perform.

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3xLLjko9/3/

```
$("#btn_save_development").bind("click", function () {

    var devMainImgSize = parseFloat(checkFilled($("#dev_main_image")) / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg1Size = parseFloat(checkFilled($("#devListingImg1")) / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg2Size = parseFloat(checkFilled($("#devListingImg2")) / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg3Size = parseFloat(checkFilled($("#devListingImg3")) / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg4Size = parseFloat(checkFilled($("#devListingImg4")) / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg5Size = parseFloat(checkFilled($("#devListingImg5")) / 1024).toFixed(2);
    var devListingImg6Size = parseFloat(checkFilled($("#devListingImg6")) / 1024).toFixed(2);

    //FOR TESTING PURPOSES
    console.log(devMainImgSize);
    console.log(devListingImg1Size);
    console.log(devListingImg2Size);
    console.log(devListingImg3Size);
    console.log(devListingImg4Size);
    console.log(devListingImg5Size);
    console.log(devListingImg6Size);

    if(devMainImgSize > 800)
    {
        alert("The Main Listing Image too large. It should not be above 800KB. Please upload an image with a smaller size");
        return false;
    }

    if (devListingImg1Size > 800 || devListingImg2Size > 800 || devListingImg3Size > 800 || devListingImg4Size > 800 || devListingImg5Size > 800 || devListingImg6Size > 800) {
        alert("One or all of the Development Listing Image(s) is above 800KB. Please ensure none of the development listing images are larger than 800KB");
        return false;
    }
});

function checkFilled(ele){
  if(ele[0].files.length > 0){
    return ele[0].files[0].size;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: nice one! Your approach brought some clarity to the issue for me and i have been able to solve it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to validate the files as the user selects them.  You could accomplish this by listening for changes on the input.

```
$("#fileInput").on("change", processFiles);

var processFiles = function(event) {
  var files = event.target.files;
  //Loop through our files  
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i += 1) {
    var file = files[i]; 
    if(file.size / 1024 > 800){
          alert("file too big!");
    }
    //Build the File Info HTML  
    var fileInfo = ["<li>",
                     file.name,
                     "<span>",
                     file.size / 1024,
                     " kb</span>", 
                     "</li>"].join(''); 
    $("#list").append(fileInfo);
    reader.onload = loaded;
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
};
```

Here is a working [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/v8Lnuwxp/3/)